# how to display two fields (and their labels) in the same row? Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two fields in out of the box sharepoint list form , both are single line of text

Is there any jquery way in which I can merge the two columns into one row

I am a newbie to coding. So I do not have much idea about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a new calculated column in the list and enter the following formula:

```
=[ColumnName1]&" "&[ColumnName2]
```

I should add that you can use the calculated column to many things, please see this article for further use: [Calculated Field Formulas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/22/comparing-list-and-form-library-forms.aspx)

**Edited**

What you could do is to customize your listform in InfoPath. In this particular case you would like to split the current cell and set the two fields in the cells next to each other.

There is some pros and cons working with InfoPath forms, but this blog should get you started with what you can do in SharePoint with InfoPath. [Comparing SharePoint List and Form Library Forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/22/comparing-list-and-form-library-forms.aspx)

And when creating/customizing a list form it will be set to the standard form for all three views. This post show you how to solve that!

[Individual New, Edit and Display forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/22/comparing-list-and-form-library-forms.aspx)

Comment: I am sorry but i want it in the form side by side. Calculated column does not appear in the form

Comment: i want days and hours in the same row as two different columns

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out, I did it by creating a new form in SPD and then using jquery to align it side by side.

Comment: I'm glad that you got it sorted out! :)